# Java access Shellfolder

Tags: java, directory, windows-shell

I am trying to access an Shellfolder like: "Shell:::{35786D3C-B075-49b9-88DD-029876E11C01}"
via Java on a Windows PC ... but I havn't found a way to do so up to now.

Is this generally possible with Java? Recently I uncovered the sun.awt class "ShellFolder"... Does this class provide the abilitiy to access such an folder?

thanks for your help Ripei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way to do it would be to create a temp folder with that name, e.g.:

```
    File file = new File("c:/temp/AnyName.{35786D3C-B075-49b9-88DD-029876E11C01}");
    boolean success = file.mkdir();
```

Works on Windows 7 for other GUIDs (seems {35786D3C-B075-49b9-88DD-029876E11C01} is for XP), don't know about prior versions.

Comment: Although the return-value is false... it works!! thank you :)